Google Sheets - Keep track of the results of a volatile function?
*** Edit #2 ***
My original issue was that functions were not playing nicely but this was resolved by turning off iterative calculations.  Now I have a related but more fundamental issue - how to keep track of the number of times a temporary value is generated randomly.

I am a teacher and I'd like to create a tool to randomly select students for different kinds of assessments; but I would like to have the option to favour less likely events (For example, if student A has done many "big" assessments, it should be less likely that they are randomly chosen for a "big" assessments in the future).  I plan to click the randomizer once per day, but want to keep track of the number of times their name comes up in each category.
Here is the link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LRJOlEJqc-i157nTuvJr47NEtbz17Upkl5dO6ML-WZY/edit?usp=sharing
When I click a checkbox, a random seed is created (in a lambda function, so the random value doesn't change unless I click the box again), which is then weighted & sorted, with the top few students being selected to do the assessment.  Every day I will uncheck, then check the box again to generate a new list.
My previous attempt to keep track of the number of times a name appeared involved a max iterative calculation of one, but this screwed up all my other functions in the sheet.
I need help in the highlighted yellow columns in the 'Class list' tab. I want Columns BCD to be the total number of times a student's name appears in columns U, AA, and AG.  Those columns are the chosen students, whose names appear and disappear as I click the checkbox in 'Randomizer'!C1.
I am an amateur when it comes to script writing. I am scared by the number of variables needed: I want it to work for 45 students, keeping track of running totals of big, medium and small assessments... 135 variables, there must be a better way. But if someone can model a solution for one student, I can try to create it for all students.
Please help math teacher who is trying to address test anxiety by offering alternative assessment styles :)
